# BeginUpdate - EndUpdate causing form to go behind all open windows

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe3, firemonkey-fm2

I have ported a control heavy application in firemonkey which I have worked upon with DXScene for little over 2 years now. The sheer number of visual controls updating on every UI change warranted the BeginUpdate-EndUpdate methods prefixed and suffixed respectively in all UI update methods.

After porting, the firemonkey engine behaves erratically to these methods.

1. Sometimes the new controls get built but not updated with contents.
2. Sometimes they don't even show and a forced form minimize-maximize gets them shown.
3. And all the time the form gets behind all the other open windows.

Is it still advisable to use these or an alternative has been introduced in FMX?